# Why is a window's position still zero after it is shown?

Tags: python, geometry, window, pyside2

I'm trying to get the `MainWindow`'s screen position after its creation.
From [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/57750/can-t-get-position-of-the-window/5) and [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/59010/why-position-always-0/9) I learned that the window geometry is set after calling `show()` - but in my case it keeps its default values and therefore the position stays zero.

---

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is to make a `QFileDialog` appear in the middle and in front of the main window. Actually, this should be the default behaviour, but because the main window's position is zero, the dialog appears in the screen's upper left corner.
The UI was created with the Qt-designer and I am loading the ui-file at runtime via the `QUiLoader`.
I noticed a few things:

- I can make the dialog appear in the middle if I set the window's position via `move()` or `setGeometry()` to its real position on the screen after `show()`.
- The geometry of the window's member `ui`, which is where the `QUiLoader` is loading the ui-file, contains the right values if I interact with the window (e.g. inside a `QPushButton`-callback) and I can set the window's geometry to the `ui`'s geometry at that point like so: `self.setGeometry(self.ui.frameGeometry())` This is what I'm doing at the moment to make the dialog appear in the middle right before showing the dialog in a certain button's callback.

(But all this is just for context.)

---

And yet I still want to know if I can make the main window have its correct position after `show()`ing it. For this reason I wrote a minimum example: One Window which is coded entirely in Python, one window which loads a ui-file to look the same as the first one and some code to make one of the windows appear:

```py
import sys, os
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtUiTools

class Window1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 200)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self, text="Print geometry")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.print_geometry)
        self.show()                                    # (A)
        # self.move(300, 200)
        self.print_geometry()                          # (C)

    def print_geometry(self):
        self.updateGeometry()                          # (E)
        print(self.frameGeometry())
        print(self.geometry())


class Window2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window2, self).__init__(parent)
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        file = QtCore.QFile(os.path.abspath("TestWindow.ui"))
        file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
        self.ui = loader.load(file, parent)
        file.close()
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.print_geometry)
        self.ui.show()                                 # (A)
        # self.ui.move(300, 200)
        self.print_geometry()                          # (C)

    def print_geometry(self):
        self.ui.updateGeometry()                       # (E)
        print(self.ui.frameGeometry())
        print(self.ui.geometry())


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = Window1()
# window = Window2()
# window.show()                                        # (B)
window.print_geometry()                                # (D)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

At first I want to mention:

- It doesn't seem to matter if I call `show()` in the end of `__init__()` or after the window was created. (A) or (B)
- It doesn't seem to matter if I call `print_geometry()` inside of `__init__()` or after the window was created. (C) or (D)
- The `updateGeometry()` calls don't seem to do anything. (E)

The output for both windows is always:

```
PySide2.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 200)
PySide2.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 200)
PySide2.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 200)
PySide2.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 200)
```

And when I click the button, the output is always:

```
PySide2.QtCore.QRect(800, 418, 302, 227)
PySide2.QtCore.QRect(801, 444, 300, 200)
```

My question is: Why does the window's geometry have default values even after `show()`, and what is happening between `show()` and the button's callback, so that the geometry suddenly contains the right values? Can I emulate this inside the window's `__init__()` after `show()`? Is this behaviour specific to Linux Mint's window manager Cinnamon, which is what I'm using?

TestWindow.ui:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>300</width>
    <height>200</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="text">
     <string>Print geometry</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour only occurs on the X11 platform (e.g. Linux) - see [Window Geometry](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html#window-geometry) and the section [X11 Peculiarities](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html#x11-peculiarities).

The key point is that on X11, certain window-related events happen *asynchronously*. This means you must wait until the window-manager has given your window a frame and positioned it on the screen before requesting the geometry. If you click a button to print the geometry, you aren't requesting it *straight away* (i.e. synchronously) - which explains why you see different output.

If you need to perform some action immediately after the window is shown that requires information about its geometry, a simple work-around is to use a single-shot timer:

```
class Window1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.show()
        # self.print_geometry()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(50, self.print_geometry)
```

In practice, the actual length of the delay will depend on the system and could be anywhere between 1ms and 25ms. You might need to experiment a bit, but 50ms should be safe.